# Laravel 5: Grabbing a single record from a query using `take`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Right now, I am using Eloquent like this: `MobileAppUsers::where('store', '=', 'store_name')->first();`  It turns out I don't need to check the `store_name` because the entire table is within that store's database, so I just want the single record that will be there (there will only be 1).

Without changing any other logic, would the equivalent of `MobileAppUsers::where('store', '=', 'store_name')->first();` (ignoring the `store_name`) be  :
`MobileAppUsers::take(1)->get();` ?

Comment: If there's only one row ever, you can just do `MobileAppUsers::first()`. I question your database design if this is the case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
MobileAppUsers::first();
```

Regards, I hope this help you